# Should I wrap all my components with React.memo() if it is not expecting any props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

While it is obvious why `React` does not perform React.memo to all its functional component by default, and we should ourself wrap our functional components as and when needed.

In my case, I have a big react project with a structure like this:

```
const MyBigApp = () => {
  const shouldShowX = useSelector(getShouldShowX);
  const shouldShowY = useSelector(getShouldShowY);
  // Many more selectors

  return (
    <>
      {shouldShowX && <ComplexComponentX />}
      {shouldShowY && <ComplexComponentY />}
      {/* many more components based on different selectors like above */}
   </>
  );
};
```

All my business logic is inside redux and the components use `useSelector` internally to get data from the store.

**Does it make sense to wrap all my child components with `React.memo`, as a change in any selector at root level causes my entire app to re-render?**

Earlier with `connect` we were automatically getting a memoized component which was comparing custom props and store value passed as props to the component, so should we now manually **always** do `React.memo` while using `useSelector` in a component not receiving any props?

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that you should consider using `React.memo` for those child components that don't accept any props. I highly recommend this article: https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/

> **2.1 Component renders often with the same props**
> The best case of wrapping a component in React.memo() is when you expect the functional
> component to render often and usually with the same props.

Since the components you're asking about don't accept any props, that means the props will never change. Therefore, it stands to reason that using `React.memo` *could* avoid render cycles. Note this important caveat from the same article:

> **5. React.memo() is a performance hint**
> Strictly, React uses memoization as a performance hint.
>
> While in most situations React avoids rendering a memoized component,
> you shouldn’t count on that to prevent rendering.

Comment: `React.memo() is a great tool to memoize functional components. When applied correctly, it prevents component useless rendering when the next props equal to previous.` so if there is no next and previous prop don't you think it is helpful? Also, consider general case of memoization, we have a complex function which does not accept any params, then it is helpful to have it inside useMemo, because the function should ideally never re-run and with useMemo it won't run again.

Comment: Yes, I think it can be helpful even if the components don't have next and previous props — especially helpful if your `shouldShow` values are changing frequently.